# Calculating mean on multiple conditions (trade data harmonization in R)

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a directed network for trade flows in R. I have export and import data, which does not always match and I would like to create the mean of the not matching values (I want to prevent having 2 flows between a dyad: Economy A exports to partner B (marked as export) and Economy B imports from reporter A (marked as import)).
I also need to group by year and Category.

```
Year Economy Partner Flow    Category value
2006 040     124     Export  S        163
```

and the other way around it looks like this

```
Year Economy Partner Flow    Category value
2006 124     040     Import  S        160
```

These are in the same dataset, but can easily be split into two.
As you can see, the value does not match, I would like to get the mean of that.
I tried the following:

```
group_by(Year, Category) %>% mutate(mean = 
case_when(Economy == Partner & Partner == Economy & Flow != Flow, 
summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = T))))
```

But this obviously does not work. I was thinking something along the lines of this could work, but it does not. And I would need to include it into a group_by call, since I have multiple years and mutliple categories.

```
function(x, y, z, b, k){
   x == y & z == b & Flow != Flow
   mean <- mean(k, na.rm = T)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Seems that this is pretty the same as what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932833/summarising-among-the-selected-rows#62933354

Comment: Could you post part of the data with `dput()`?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to do that already but this crashes R even with head() (its A LOT of data). Is there a way to reduce that?

Comment: You could produce some dummy data that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about converting all your trades in imports (or exports)?

Starting with a `df` with your columns' names:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Flow == "Export") %>%
  mutate(aux = Economy, Economy = Partner, Partner = aux,
         Flow = "Import") %>%
  select(-aux) -> tmp
rbind(df, tmp) %>%
  filter(Flow == "Import") -> df2
```

In `df2` you should have the same information as in `df`, but now `group_by` and `summarise` operations should be straightforward.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing but considerably more complicated than you. Thank you! shortening scripts is always good.